# How to use ArrayList properly?

Tags: java, arrays, list

Okay so using ArrayLists is a first for me, and I would consult my teacher or friends for help first...but its an online course so asking questions takes forever, and as of now I am the only student taking this course in my entire school (It's a pretty small school.)

Anyways, this is so simple it's ridiculous (for you I would suppose) however it's getting rid of the underlined things...so I'm guessing I'm missing a key component...

```
public class EmployeeProjectView extends FrameView {
```

For example take this line...the beginning of this program, `company` is underlined red (I'm using netbeans) and I'm not sure why, it works fine as `String` so my question is....does it always have to be defined as a `String`?

```
/** Define the ArrayList */
ArrayList<company> employee = new ArrayList<company>();


public EmployeeProjectView(SingleFrameApplication app) {
}// </editor-fold>
```

This (below for "addButton") is where you store the information in the array.

```
private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

String c;
String ID, firstName, lastName, salary, date;

ID = IDField.getText();
firstName = firstNameField.getText();
salary = annualSalField.getText();
date = startDateField.getText();
```

new `String`  is underlined red...

```
 c = new String(ID, firstName, lastName, salary, date);
    employee.add(c);

}                                         

private void listButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

//Code here gets listed in Field...

    }
```

Comment: @Que.. Do you have a class named Company?

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` expects a type in between `< >`.  String is a type, in your example company seems to be a variable.  What type should the `employee` list have?  Is employee a list of Strings?  Is it a list of some user-defined class?  You need to know this.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

As an example:

```
ArrayList<UserDefinedClass> myList = 
    new ArrayList<UserDefinedClass>(initialCapacity);
// initialCapacity should be a previously defined int.
// Or
ArrayList<String> someNames = new ArrayList<String>();
// Uses a default capacity of 10 when none is provided.
```

Secondly, String is a funny (but very handy) object in Java.  Strings should not be created using the `new` keyword, but rather assigned just as you would a primitive like `int` `char` or `short`. This is due to something called "string interning" which merits a Google search on its own.  To assign a String:

`String word = "Strong Bad";`

Answer (score 0):

> For example take this line...the beginning of this program, "company"
>   is underlined red (I'm using netbeans) and I'm not sure why, it works
>   fine as "String" so my question is....does it always have to be
>   defined as a String?

No. Go read about Generics. The `ArrayList` can be defined as taking any type. So your declaration is fine as long as `company` is a class name. By the way, class names should always use uppercase for the first letter to follow the usual convention.

Judging by your line `c = new String(ID, firstName, lastName, salary, date);` you need to learn about Objects in Java. String is a type of Object. Look at the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for the String class: there is no constructor that accepts other Strings as parameters in the order you coded. Therefore you cannot construct a new String the way you are trying to. You seem to be confused about how Strings are initialized. It basically looks like you need to read a Java tutorial about constructing Objects, and what classes and methods are.

Comment: Ouch, it is just me, or did this answer come off as a little hostile?

Comment: @BlackVegetable that wasn't the intention. I didn't re-read my post before I submitted though. Edited to sound less hostile though. edit: better?

Comment: I feel as though your edit is more or less the same then your first answer, but whichever =P who cares?

Comment: @Que At least it's honest. I don't see how writing your code for you would be helpful. I answered your question about why you're getting your error. I also told you about what concepts you should learn to understand why you're getting the error. That's a lot more helpful than giving you an exact code sample to fix your problem, which I will not do.

Comment: @KyleM and I respect that, I was not asking for the correct code to be done for me (though...to be honest, as a student it's an added bonus)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted to do :

```
 List<String> c = new ArrayList<String>(5);
 c.add(ID);
 c.add(firstName);
```

etc..

There is a convenient method in Arrays class for this :

```
Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's saying there is no definition of company, so it doesn't know what to do an array list of.

`ArrayList<String>` it does understand because it knows the definition of string.

new String(ID, ... ) Well now it's looking through the definition of string for a constructor that takes five string arguments, and struggling...

You might also want to think a bit more about your names a collection of company called employee is bound to lead you into a bad place. Strings called Date and Salary aren't a good thing either.

Answer (score 0):

Following might help you..

```
ArrayList<Company> employee=new ArrayList<Company>();

Company employee1=new Company();
employee1.setId(id)
employee1.setFirstname(firstname);
employee1.setSalary(salary);
employee1.setDate(dates);

employee.add(employee1);
```

You must have a Company class something like this

```
class Company {
String id,firstname,lastname,salary,dates;

//setter   getter method
```

(You can achieve this in Netbeans by right click->Insert Code-> setter and getter)

cheers,